# How to connect to Apache OfBiz from .NET

Tags: .net, ofbiz

What are the ways to connect to [Apache OfBiz](http://ofbiz.apache.org/) from a .NET application?

I would like to know how can I get data from ofbiz and how I can update date from the .NET application into ofbiz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you only want to retrieve/modify data? Why don't you connect directly to the database? If you need something more complex you could implement webservices using SOAP ( or RMI ) this tutorial should help you [SOAP/RMI tutorial or ofbiz](http://www.opensourcestrategies.com/ofbiz/OFBIZ_SOAP_RMI_Tutorial.pdf)